# Estimate on smooth functional

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, implicit-differentiation, functional-inequalities

Let $f:H\to H' $ be a smooth map, between two Hilbert spaces. 
Suppose that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism, i.e. $f: B_\epsilon\to B'_{\epsilon'}$ is differentiable, and there exists $g:B'_{\epsilon'} \to B_\epsilon$, such that $f(g)=I$, and 
$$\|Df(x)^{-1}\|,\|Dg(y)\|\leq C_1,\|D^2g(y)\|\leq C_2.$$

We know that there exists a constant $c$ such that there exists a unique $h\in H$ $\|h\|_H\leq c$, we have $f(h)=0$.

**Q**: How to show that 
$$\|h\|_H\leq const \|f(0)\|_{H'}.$$

Comment: You are not assuming that $g(f) = Id$ is that correct? Since I, unfortunately, used that property in my now-deleted answer.

Comment: @P.Pet Sorry, I do not know if it is necessary or not. If we assume it, then, you could show the inequality, is this right?

Comment: I undeleted my attempt, but I am not entirely happy.

Answer (score 2):

Being not knowledgeable enough to solve the problem as is, I had to additionally assume $g(f)(0) = 0$. This makes things considerably easier.

Since $h$ is unique, you know that $h = g(0)$. Hence
$$
\|h\|_{H} = \|g(0)\|_{H} \leq \|g(0)- g(f(0))\|_{H} + \|g(f(0))\|_{H}.
$$
You have by assumption that $g(f(0)) = 0$ and thus 
$$
\|h\|_{H} \leq \|g(0)- g(f(0))\|_{H}.
$$
Finally, we have $\|g(0)- g(f(0))\|_{H} \leq C_2 \| f(0)\|_{H'}$ by the mean value theorem for Gateaux derivatives, which you can find everywhere.